# OPENCV : CUDA context initialization for different methods

Tags: c++, opencv, unix, ubuntu, cuda

I'm working on a simple c++ program to evaluate the performance of some Opencv GPU methods (cv::cuda). 
I am using Opencv 3.1 on Ubuntu 15 (with CUDA 7.5) with a GeForce 770.

I previously read that we need to initialize CUDA environment to avoid slow process at first call. So, I initialize my program with a cv::cuda::getDevice() and setDevice().

Then, I test 2 methods:

- cv::cuda::resize() (factor 0.5)
- and cv::cuda::meanStdDev.

Initialization takes 400ms. Then, resizing takes 2 or 3 ms, that's OK. 
But... meanStdDev takes 476ms! 
If I run 2 successive meanStdDev, the second one is much faster (3ms).

I really don't understand why the initialization has an effect on resize() but not on meanStdDev().

I compile OPENCV with -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=3.0. I try with -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX="" but the problem is still the same.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    double t_init_cuda = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    int CudaDevice;
    if(cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()==0)
    {
        cerr<<endl<<"ERROR: NO CudaEnabledDevice"<<endl;
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        CudaDevice = cv::cuda::getDevice();
        cv::cuda::setDevice(CudaDevice);
    }
    t_init_cuda = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t_init_cuda)/cv::getTickFrequency() * 1000;
    cout<<endl<<"\t*T_INIT_CUDA="<<t_init_cuda<<"ms\n";;

    cv::Mat src = cv::imread(argv[1], 0);
    if (!src.data) exit(1);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_src(src);


    //CV::CUDA::RESIZE
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_dst;
    double factor = 0.5;
    double t_gpu_resize = cv::getTickCount();
    cv::cuda::resize(d_src, d_dst, cv::Size( (int) ((float) (d_src.cols)*factor) , (int) ((float) (d_src.rows)*factor)), 0, 0, CV_INTER_AREA);
    t_gpu_resize = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t_gpu_resize)/cv::getTickFrequency() * 1000;
    cout<<endl<<"D_SRC="<<d_src.rows<<"x"<<d_src.cols<<" => D_DST="<<d_dst.rows<<"x"<<d_dst.cols<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"\t*T_GPU_RESIZE="<<t_gpu_resize<<"ms\n";;

    //CV::CUDA::MEANSTDDEV
    double t_meanstddev = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    cv::Scalar mean, stddev;
    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> d_src_split;
    cv::cuda::split(d_src, d_src_split);
    cv::cuda::meanStdDev (d_src_split[0], mean, stddev); 
    t_meanstddev = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t_meanstddev)/cv::getTickFrequency() * 1000.0;
    cout<<endl<<"mean="<<mean.val[0]<<" | stddev="<<stddev.val[0]<<endl;    
    cout<<endl<<"\t*T_GPU_MEANSTDDEV="<<t_meanstddev<<"ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you stop timer before  dst.createMatHeader().copyTo(Mat(1, 2, CV_64FC1, &vals[0]));  in cv::cuda::meanStdDev method? maybe copying from gpu to cpu takes that much time. I don't have the setup to try right now.

Comment: are you sure that you measure the times correctly? If the cuda kernel is executed asynchronously (afaik that's default) your CPU isn't blocked if you don't access the cuda result. Is there a way to force the synchronization in OpenCV? Maybe (really just a maybe), atm you start time measurement before the `resize`, and use some point DURING the resize as the starting point for your `meanStdDev`, which will have to wait for the resize to finish, so you sum up reasize and meansStdDev times both in the second period. I don't know much about the OpenCV Cuda stuff, only plain cuda.

Comment: @Micka thanks for your reply. Actually, I try to access the results of both methods (resize and meanStdDev) but the problem is still the same. Initialization with dummy call of resize and meanStddev works but it's not a great solution for me... I will try to explore the CUDA_DEVCODE_CACHE environnement variable "to use a compilation cache which is persistent over multiple runs" as (very briefly) mentioned in the opencv wiki...

Comment: But the first call of "resize" is slow in this case, too? That probably means `cv::cuda::getDevice() and setDevice()` does not initialize both of your kernels (your initial assumption was that it did initialize the resize but not the meanStdDev). Probably, the JIT compiler is called instead when the kernel is used for the first time. Maybe you can find out what is needed to prevent JIT compilation (maybe if you specify CMake parameters exactly for your hardware).

Comment: No, the first call of resize() is very fast with a setDevice() (and very slow without initialization) but has -strangely- no impact for the first call of meanStdDev(). I try to avoid PTX generation when compiling OpenCV and to specify my arch (CUDA_ARCH_BIN=3.0) but with no result.

Comment: can you tell me what "setDevice" should do? Doc says it "initializes the device", it doesn't say anything about the kernels. However if you don't call setDevice, the device initialization will be performed on the first cuda call. Can you try to revert the order of resize and meanStdDev (with and without device initialization) to get more information about the behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

My friend, When you call same function twice :

1- First time you allocate new memory at Device for resized. "According to WIKI of [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/matrix_reductions.html)"

2- Second time you reuse allocated memory so it will be fast.

I get that function from OpenCV for you so you can understand why it said that.

```
void cv::cuda::meanStdDev(InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, Stream& stream)
{
    if (!deviceSupports(FEATURE_SET_COMPUTE_13))
        CV_Error(cv::Error::StsNotImplemented, "Not sufficient compute capebility");

    const GpuMat src = getInputMat(_src, stream);

    CV_Assert( src.type() == CV_8UC1 );

    GpuMat dst = getOutputMat(_dst, 1, 2, CV_64FC1, stream);

    NppiSize sz;
    sz.width  = src.cols;
    sz.height = src.rows;

    int bufSize;
#if (CUDA_VERSION <= 4020)
    nppSafeCall( nppiMeanStdDev8uC1RGetBufferHostSize(sz, &bufSize) );
#else
    nppSafeCall( nppiMeanStdDevGetBufferHostSize_8u_C1R(sz, &bufSize) );
#endif

    BufferPool pool(stream);
    GpuMat buf = pool.getBuffer(1, bufSize, CV_8UC1); // <--- this line create new GpuMat

    NppStreamHandler h(StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));

    nppSafeCall( nppiMean_StdDev_8u_C1R(src.ptr<Npp8u>(), static_cast<int>(src.step), sz, buf.ptr<Npp8u>(), dst.ptr<Npp64f>(), dst.ptr<Npp64f>() + 1) );

    syncOutput(dst, _dst, stream);
}
```

this function

```
GpuMat cv::cuda::BufferPool::getBuffer(int rows, int cols, int type)
{
    GpuMat buf(allocator_);
    buf.create(rows, cols, type);
    return buf;
}
```

I hope this will help you.