# Initialize Cuda for the first time in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Always, the first operation with CUDA is too expensive due to initialization time. I read somewhere that I may apply any simple CUDA operation to initialize it before doing the actual work. Currently I am doing:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat test;
test.create(1, 1, CV_8U);
test.release();
```

It works fine. However, I just did not like it. It seems so stupid to put this code in the beginning of the program.

Is there a standard way to initialize CUDA? for example something like:

```
cv::cuda::initial(); //Imaginary code
```

Comment: Why not just let initialization happen whenever it would naturally occur?  Why do you need to force it?

Comment: The program does not start immediately processing images. At first it may ask for some input. At this time, inilizing cuda will not be noticed.

Comment: You can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150811/opencv-cuda-context-initialization-for-different-methods